# Include file no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

tenho um site criado em wordpress e preciso incluir o comando

```
include 'config.php';
```

com algumas funções específicas que preciso usar (inclusive acesso a um banco de dados externo).

porém, em todas as páginas que eu incluo esse código dá erro.

já tentei nas páginas do tema, na functions.php, no header.php e até agora só dá erro.

alguma dica de como incluir o comando acima (ou outro que faça a mesma função)?

abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa incluir o caminho completo, mesmo que o arquivo esteja dentro do tema. ex.:

```
// /path/do/wordpress/wp-content/theme/nome-do-tema/config.php
include get_template_directory().'/config.php';

// http://example.com/wp-content/theme/nome-do-tema/config.php
include get_template_directory_uri().'/config.php';
```

Existem diversas funções úteis, além de constantes do sistema pra deteminar `paths` e `uris` dentro do WordPress.

[Aqui uma listagem completa delas na documentação oficial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)